# How to cast template class ptr to normal class ptr in C++

Tags: c++, templates, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I have question regarding macros. How could I cast through macro a template class to normal class. In example:

```
#define RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name) ((CRuntimeClass*)(&class##class_name))

template<typename T> A {};

if (RUNTIME_CLASS(A));
```

I know that this code wouldn't compile because it will not see template bit. But I don't understand the actual macro. the return of it looks like `(CRuntimeClass*)(&classA)`

Why `##` concatenate makes class + A ? and how preprocessor understands such notation?

Comment: ## is a useful feature of the preprocessor. It allows to create tokens by concatenation.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. 
What difference does it make whether the class is a template?
It also looks like you want to take a *type* (A) and cast that to a pointer. You can't. Types are not values. Do you want to cast an *object* of type `A*` to `CRuntimeClass*`? And how do you know it is safe to cast it to a `CRuntimeClass*`?

Please explain what problem you're trying to solve. Then we can tell you if it is possible, and how you should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe where you took the macro all the class names are starting with "class" and the macro expects only the second part of the name, what comes after "class".

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question.

First - I don't understand why you'd want to cast a template class into a normal class. The way to convert a template class into a concrete class is to supply the template parameters. Without those parameters, the template class has not been fully defined, and therefore simply cannot be used.

In a way, a template is a function that is evaluated at compile time in order to define a class/function. Without the parameters, trying to treat the template as a class is like trying to treat an unevaluated function as a number.

As already mentioned, "##" is a token concatenating preprocessor operator. If you aren't expecting that, I don't understand why you are writing "##".

Is this something to do with name mangling?

Answer (score 0):

That's just what it does, ## concatenates a string and a parameter passed into your #define.